# string compare in javascript that returns a boolean

Tags: javascript

Is there a function in javascript that compares a string and returns a boolean? I found .match but it returns the strings that matched. I was hoping there was something else so that I would have a lesser code in comparing a string. Since I wanted to check if a string has this word and proceed else not.

thanks

Comment: are you looking for an exact string1 to string2 match, or is string1 something that can occur somewhere within a larger string2?

Comment: that was my first solution but i encountered a flaw. Email == Friend Email will return false. so i was looking for a strcmp like function for javascript. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use type **augmentation**, especially if you need to use this function often:

```
String.prototype.isMatch = function(s){
   return this.match(s)!==null 
}
```

So you can use:

```
var myBool = "ali".isMatch("Ali");
```

---

General view is that use of type augmentation is *discouraged* only because of the fact that it can collide with other augmentations.

According to [Javascript Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0046RERXE/ref=docs-os-doi_0) book, its use must be limited.

I personally think it is OK, as long as you use a good naming such as:

```
String.prototype.mycompany_isMatch = function(s){
   return this.match(s)!==null 
}
```

This will make it **ugly** but **safe**.

Comment: Great! (a little bit overkill maybe? :D)

Comment: i have not seen those things before. what is ismatch? let me try this. thanks

Comment: @magicianIam it will work if you add it to the string prototype - as I have outlined. `isMatch` is our addition to JavaScript framework, not an intrinsic function

Comment: There is no "isMatch" method in String. what Aliostad want to explain is that you can augment javascript object functionality by defining a new function and adding it to it's prototype.
Have a look at http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html fore something more

Comment: IMO this is overkill if all he needs it for is a single condition.. this method would be better if you need to make use of this in a lot of places

Comment: @CrayonViolent yes. My point was that it is good to be implemented as augmenting if used often.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the RegEx `test()` method which returns a boolean:

```
/a/.test('abcd'); // returns true.
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  "The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns `true` or `false`." -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 5):

there is `.indexOf()` which will return the position of the string found, or -1 if not found

Comment: i've always thought that was only for array.

Comment: nope, it works on strings as well! But I'm a bit unclear as to whether you are looking for a substring within a string, or exact (case insenstive?) string comparison..

Comment: case sensitive, but i am planning to use tolowercase to ease up my problems. let me try this one. thanks. wonder why google didn't showed me this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.indexOf(myWord) > -1
```

or, if you want a function:

```
function hasWord(myString, myWord) {
  return myString.indexOf(myWord) > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a compare.

```
if ("dog" == "cat") {
  DoSomethingIfItIsTrue();
} else {
    DoSomethingIfItIsFalse();
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you take this approach, you want to use '===', not '=='.  I suspect that most Javascript coders would use this rather than augment the String prototype, so it's worth at least getting people in the habit of using '===' for checking equality.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the exact answer you are looking for but this is always an effective way to do this.

```
if(var1 == var2){
  //do this
}else{
  //do that
};
```

Comment: according to large number of articles (and my personal opinion too) the `===`test is far more reliable (and have transitivity propery) than `==`(which is not transitive). Moreover, if he needs a boolean he can just use `(var1 === var2 ? true: false)`

Comment: Yes I understand he wants to return a boolean but what is he going to do with it after, my assumption would be to do something if it is true and something else if it is false. But yes, you are correct with the ===.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `.match()`can do the trick for you because it returns an array of pattern matching strings if any, null otherwise.

Anyway, if you just want to check if a string contain another string you're more likely to use  `indexOf()` (it will return -1 if no substring is found).

The first solution is a bit overkill for your purpose.

If on the other end you want to check for equality you can use `string1 === string2``

Answer (score 0):

### If anyone still has doubts ...

It was quoted by another colleague using the `indexOf()` method. The return of this method is either "-1", if it does not find the String in the Array, or the position of the case it finds.

To use it with the desired return, you would have to perform a check before, such as:

```
exampleMethod () {
const expression = ['string1', string2] .indexOf (this.exampleObject);
if (expression! = -1) {
 return true;
  } else return false;
}
```

Basically, you would take advantage of this return.

However, the `includes()` method can simply be used:

```
exampleMethode(): boolean {
  return ['string1', 'string2'].includes(this.exampleObject);
}
```

The return of this method will do what you want in a simple way. Compares the object string with the string array you want to check, and returns a boolean.